# Feature 'Backup of a database containing a columnar table' is not supported by MemSQL

Tags: singlestore

MemSQL doesn't support backup of columnar tables:

```
memsql> backup database stat to '/data/memsql-backup';
ERROR 1706 (HY000): Feature 'Backup of a database containing a columnar table' is not supported by MemSQL.
```

How to organize online backup in this case? Through export to CSV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, yes, exporting columnstore tables to a file is the recommended solution. The select into outfile command or the mysqldump do the job well.

http://docs.memsql.com/4.0/ref/SELECT/

Comment: As I understand this functionality will be implemented in the future. Do you have any estimates when it can be implemented?

Comment: BACKUP of databases with columnstore tables is supported in MemSQL 5 and above.

Answer (score 1):

`mysqldump`ing the columnar table is your best bet for an online backup in this case. If in the future you would like to run the `BACKUP` command on the entire database, (for the time being) it is recommended that you move your columnar table to a different database in the cluster.